# How to show Price Variance in Result Set (Purchase Order Pricing)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping, aggregate-functions

I am trying to track some of our purchases in our ERP software.
In short, I want to know if we paid one price for something a month ago and a different price this month, it should return the 2 Purchase Orders, stock code, Price and date etc.

My Code

```
select DISTINCT(MStockCode), PurchaseOrder, MPrice, MOrigDueDate from PorMasterDetail
where MStockCode <>''
and YEAR(MOrigDueDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
and month(MOrigDueDate) = month(GETDATE())
AND MPrice >'0'
ORDER BY MStockCode ASC
```

When I put this in Sql Reporting Services, it gives a valid output (below)
It shows all the StockCodes, grouped with the Purchase Orders underneath, price paid and date.

*650-1757  $1,554.00
323639 $518.00 4/12/2014
323784 $518.00 22/12/2014
323787 $518.00 22/12/2014

0075-018  $175.33
323427 $59.04 3/12/2014
323498 $59.04 3/12/2014
323547 $57.25 17/12/2014

0075-042  $766.56
323456 $389.17 3/12/2014
323597 $377.39 17/12/2014

0075-050  $11.55
323476 $11.55 3/12/2014

0075-210  $19.50
323328 $9.75 3/12/2014
323417 $9.75 3/12/2014

In an ideal output, it would only show the below as these have different prices

0075-018  $175.33
323427 $59.04 3/12/2014
323498 $59.04 3/12/2014
323547 $57.25 17/12/2014

0075-042  $766.56
323456 $389.17 3/12/2014
323597 $377.39 17/12/2014

Would it be best, putting it in a subquery, or refining in SSRS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: expected output is not clear

Comment: The output I'd like to have, is only the StockCodes that we've purchased that have a different purchaseprice (mprice)

Comment: still it is not clear update the expected output in table format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using SQL Server 2008 for this example.

In the question you say that you are interested in two months, but in the query you look only at the current month and in a rather inefficient way. So, I explicitly added two parameters that define the range of dates that you are interested in.

The CTE_Changed gets a list of `MStockCode`s, for which the price changed within the given range of dates (inclusive). Then you just retrieve all necessary details for found `MStockCode`s.

I assume that MPrice column has a `money` type, not a `char` type, so I changed comparison to `> 0` instead of `> '0'`.

```
DECLARE @ParamStartDate date = '2014-11-01';
DECLARE @ParamEndDate date = '2014-12-31';

WITH
CTE_Changed
AS
(
    SELECT
        MStockCode
    FROM
        PorMasterDetail
    WHERE
        MStockCode <> ''
        AND MOrigDueDate >= @ParamStartDate
        AND MOrigDueDate <= @ParamEndDate
        AND MPrice > 0
    GROUP BY
        MStockCode
    HAVING
        MIN(MPrice) <> MAX(MPrice)
)
SELECT
    PorMasterDetail.MStockCode
    ,PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder
    ,PorMasterDetail.MPrice
    ,PorMasterDetail.MOrigDueDate
FROM
    CTE_Changed
    INNER JOIN PorMasterDetail ON PorMasterDetail.MStockCode = CTE_Changed.MStockCode
ORDER BY PorMasterDetail.MStockCode
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, you've pointed me in the right direction, however using your code   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Well. You didn't provide a script to recreate your data schema and sample data. So, I wrote the query blindfolded. You can't expect people to write syntactically correct code without possibility to compile and run it. Anyway, I've edited my question and I think I've fixed that syntax error. Please try it again.

Comment: It was helpful, just letting you know.  Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful for you.